Engine Misfire: Which is cylinder 2? 2007 Hyundai Santa Fe
I have a 2007 Hyundai Santa Fe that gave me error code: P0302 - cylinder 2 misfire
How do I identify which of the coils is cylinder 2? There are 3 on the front (bottom of pic) and then 3 on the back underneath that silver thing. The picture was taken with me facing the hood from the front of the car.



On this Hyundai engine, the #1 cylinder is located to the back bank (by the fire wall). This is the most forward cylinder (to the front of the engine, not to the front of the car) of the six. The next most forward cylinder is the #2, which is in the bank at the front of the car. The cylinders alternate from there on each bank. Here's an image of what I'm saying:

Most vehicle manufacturers number their cylinders this way, with the forward most (in the engine) being the #1 cylinder. You have to check though, as some manufacturers do crazy things.
The silver thing is the upper intake manifold. In Hyundai's infinite wisdom, they made it so you have to remove this in order get to the back coils and plugs. If you have to take this off for any reason, replace the gasket (which is a metal shim) between the two parts so it will seal properly.

Is there a way to check besides changing that spark plug / coil and seeing if the error goes away?

@sushi - Swapping coils & plugs is the easiest way to diagnose coil/plug issues. Mind you, the problem won't go away with diagnosis. The #2 is in front of you when looking at the engine, so swapping the 2&4 plug/coil is very easy & non-problematic. Change them out one at a time (ie: change only coils). If the problem doesn't follow the part, try the other part. If it still doesn't follow, next to check would be the injector. Work from easiest to hardest (ie: coil; plug; injector). Diagnose all of these parts without buying anything, though fuel is a little more problematic than spark.

If coil swapping still results in cyl #2 misfire, P0302, removing spark plugs may reveal wear. When were spark plugs replaced? If they're platinum/iridium plugs, they may go as long as 100k miles before replacing them.
